# str_replace value which starts with x and end with x

Tags: php, web, str-replace

i want to use the str_replace function for change many value like this;

```
<p><a href="gogole.com">gogole</a>a ramdom text</p>
```

to

```
<p>a ramdom text</p>
```

or again

```
<p><a style="color:red;" href="stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>a ramdom text</p>
```

to

```
<p>a ramdom text</p>
```

so how i can do it ? thanks

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: i tried to search and dont have any idea if its possible

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8868da89ae2bff83b8700c2ab9fee0800a64d93a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the string you want to replace is not completely predictible, what you need to use is a regular expression. Here is a quick and dirty one for this case, using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = '<p><a href="gogole.com">gogole</a>a ramdom text</p>';
$stripped = preg_replace("/<a .*?<\/a>/", "", $string);
```

but regular expressions can be tricky, so be careful.

**Edit:** fixed expression as suggested in comments. Another possibility could be `/<a [^<]*<\/a>/`.

Comment: This won't work very well for `<p><a href="1">first link</a>a ramdom text<a href="1">more links</a></p>`. Perhaps `<a .*?<\/a>`

Comment: I had just realized the same thing, good catch, thanks! Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position at the start like:

```
$start = strpos($myString, "<a ");
```

and the end like:

```
$end = strpos($myString, "</a>" + 4);
```

and then:

```
$myNewString = substr($myString, 0, $start).substr($myString, $end);
```

Of course you will need to watch out for edge cases, like `<a>` or `</a>` not being in the string or the string ends with `</a>`.